# Equation and aligning

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, align, alignat

I need help. I need to write these equations in LaTeX, I wrote it like this:

```
\newcounter{defcounter} 
\setcounter{defcounter}{23}
\newenvironment{myequation}%
   {\addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
    \refstepcounter{defcounter}%
    \renewcommand\theequation{D.\thedefcounter}%
    \begin{equation}
   }%
   {\end{equation}%
   }

\begin{myequation}
   (x^{\alpha})' \ = \ \alpha x^{\alpha -1}, \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \ x \in 
\mathbb{R}
\end{myequation}

\begin{myequation}
   (\log_a{x})' \ = \ \frac{1}{x}\log_a{e}, \ x>0 \\
\end{myequation}
```

to get the numbers on the right side.
I also have a Section so if I use align he automatically put number 2.3 which I don't need
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should rather use `\begin{align} ...\end{align}` instead of such `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` wrapper. `equation` itself is numbered already, so there is no need to number it again with a different counter, in my point of view.

Comment: it is myequation because i need to have D.24 if i put only equation it will be numbered as 1

Comment: You could as well set `equation` to `23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases such wrapper environments are not really well-designed and the alignment can be done with `align` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}



\renewcommand\theequation{D.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{23}
\begin{align}
(x^{\alpha})'  &=  \alpha x^{\alpha -1}, \,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \, x \in 
\mathbb{R} \\
(\log_a{x})'  &=  \frac{1}{x}\log_a{e}, \,x>0 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So here is another problem